# How to animation in image detection in arkit swift

Tags: swift, swift4, augmented-reality, arkit

Little questions on #arkit and #imageDetection, When my camera recognizes an image. It shows the content right after it recognizes. So my question is how can I add animation so it looks a little nicer.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the node opacity to 0 by default and run the [fadeIn](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnaction/1522777-fadein) [SCNAction](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnaction) when the image is recognized.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to get a compelling animated model in your app is to use a predefined animation that was made in such 3D apps as Autodesk Maya, Autodesk 3dsMax, or Maxon Cinema4D.

After creating an animation in any of aforementioned 3D package you need to bake this animation (*baking is a process of keyframe generation for every frame instead of using interpolated curve*) and export this scene as a .dae file format. `ARKit`/`SceneKit` supports not only `.dae` animations but also brand-new `.usdz` file format.

SceneKit API, as well as ARKit API, are not designed for 3D animation.